# What is the OID to get number of CPU cores in SNMP

Tags: snmp

Does anyone knows what is the OID to get the number of CPU cores in SNMP? I want to get an Integer value for this.

Thank you.

Comment: That depends entirely on what MIBs your host provides!  It's also possible that information isn't available from SNMP at all on your host.

Comment: FoggyDay, your comment could be a decent answer to this question, I think. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a SNMP walk of this OID: `1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2` it will return the load for each CPU, you can simple count the results and you will know the numbers of cores.

That OID `1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2` follows the HOST-RESOURCES-MIB from Standards / RFCs, so it should work on other platforms. 
http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.html

My sample code using SharpSnmpLib:

```
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      var result = new List<Variable>();
      Messenger.BulkWalk(VersionCode.V2,
                     new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.10.10.23"), 161),
                     new OctetString("public"),
                     new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2"),
                     result,
                     6000,
                     10,
                     WalkMode.WithinSubtree,
                     null,
                     null);
    }
  }
}
```

`result`'s count will be `4` as I'm using an Intel i5 with 4 cores.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [NETSNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org) version based on the previous answer by @celso-catarino-neto

```
➜ snmptable -M +.  -m +ALL -v 2c -c public -Pu -Ci  mylinuxserver  HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorTable
SNMP table: HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorTable

 index        hrProcessorFrwID hrProcessorLoad
   768 SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero              42
   769 SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero              32
   770 SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero              40
   771 SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero              37
```

The OID for the [hrProcessorTable](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/host.html#hrProcessorTable)  is ...

```
➜ snmptranslate -M+. -m +ALL  -On  HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorTable
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use snmpwalk tool for it.

```
$ snmpwalk -c public <machine ip-addr> 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2 | wc -l
```

It will return an integer as a desired number of CPU cores